# symfony undefined variable after empty query passing to twig

Tags: variables, symfony, undefined

I have function in my repository... everything works greate when they are some data... but when not:

> error: undefined variable $followees_ids appear...

```
public function foreachFolloweesToFolloweesIds($followees)
{
    foreach ($followees as $followee) {
        $followees_ids[]=$followee['id'];
    } 

    if (empty($followees_ids)) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return $followees_ids;
    }
}
```

It could be done as i wrote if (empty ... bla bla but it seems to be not written very well... and i will use it a lot so some best practise would be greate. How can i write it better to defend the variable from being undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, your method returns an array of (what you called) followees_ids,

Even if I don't understand what this method is used for, I would suggest using [Early return](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=1421) to check if $followees contains elements.

So, you've to add on the top of your method,

```
if (empty($followees)) {
    return array(); // or null
}
```

**Also,**

- You've to first initialize the array your method returns.
- You don't really need an else statement when you return early.

Comment: its for creating an array with ids. And hm intresting article thx. i used your way and early return.

Comment: You're welcome, you don't really need the if/else statement you put at the end.

Comment: yes i know thx :P I just was looking for some nicer method than i used and your seems  to be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a

```
$followees_ids = array();
```

before the foreach so $followees_ids isn't undefined even if you don't have any results.

Comment: +1 to that. Initialising the variable prior to adding elements to it *is* the correct way to do that.